# S3_TransferManager example demo

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, awss3transfermanager

I am trying to run AWS [S3_TransferManager](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_TransferManager) sample android app. I have replaced my AWS details in Constants.java file. Now when I try to run the app, it runs without an error, when I click "Upload An Image", and chooses a image, it shows me the progress bar but it doesn't upload it. The progress bar stays idle.
IAM->Roles->Inline Policy

```
Policy Name - S3
Show Policy - {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["s3:PutObject"],
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::uni-cloud/*"]
}
]
}
```

and my bucket name is "uni-cloud", and permissions for bucket is

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::uni-cloud/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What and where I am doing it wrong?
Thanks

Comment: This action s3:ListMultipartUploadParts is needed to abort multipart uploads.

Comment: I added this, but it still the same. Doesn't upload, and stays idle. Can you please have a look at this question instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861887/error-while-uploading-file-to-amazon-s3-bucket